# Título dinámico en JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

soy un principiante aprendiendo JavaFX, el problema que tengo es que en mi programa quiero colocar un título que cambia cada que se use un una variable string, que esta variable String obtenga el valor de un choiceBox, y coloque el texto en el título. Intente colocar un nodo textField, un textArea y un Text para realizar esta acción con el método setText(), sin embargo al leer documentación de JavaFX, entiendo que estos nodos sólo pueden mostrar texto ingresado por el usuario (si me equivoco, agradecería la corrección),¿Cómo puedo realizar dicha acción?. Saludos

Comment: textfield y textarea si pueden tener texto ingresado en el código , pero son editables por el usuario cuando están en ejecución ( si así se estipula  en el método que ambos tienen .setEditable( boolean)). si no es editable ; el usuario no puede cambiarlo

Answer (score 1):

**cambiar título de `Stage` con `ComboBox` y  `TextField`**

[image: cambiar título stage javafx]

`ComboBox` tiene una propiedad que puede ser escuchada `valueProperty()` toda vez que se selecciona un nuevo valor para el objeto comboBox éste le pasa el `String` a stage en `stage.setTitle(comboBox.getValue())`. lo mismo con `TextField` toda vez que se actualiza el text este le pasa `stage.setTitle(textField.getText())`

Esta es una aplicación **JavaFX** en una sola clase que puede probar

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        
        ObservableList<String> values =FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        values.addAll("titulo1","titulo2","titulo3");
        
        
        ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox = new ChoiceBox<String>(values);
        choiceBox.valueProperty().addListener(e-> stage.setTitle(choiceBox.getValue()));
        
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setPromptText("cambiar título");
        textField.textProperty().addListener((o) -> { 
            stage.setTitle(textField.getText());
        });
        
        HBox hBox = new HBox(choiceBox,textField);
        hBox.setSpacing(20);
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

     
        Scene scene = new Scene(hBox, 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```